# Pattern matching on singleton type parametrized by abstract parameters

Tags: scala

I would be really appreciated if someone could explain in details compiler's logic during this strange cast between two type parameters

```
def unsafeCoerce[A, B]: A => B = {
  val a = implicitly[A =:= A]
  implicitly[B =:= B] match {
    case _: a.type => implicitly[A =:= B]
  }
}
```

Can be executed

```
scala> Some(unsafeCoerce[String, Int]("hi"))
res0: Some[Int] = Some(hi)
```

Why compiler allowed to compile implicitly[A =:= B]?

This example was taken from [here](https://typelevel.org/blog/2014/07/06/singleton_instance_trick_unsafe.html).

Comment: FYI. Tried this out on [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/). Dotty won't compile: "Cannot prove that A =:= B."

Comment: @jwvh It does not seem to compile on newer versions of scala (2.11 and newer). For version 2.10.6 it works as described in the question.

Comment: The linked page already gives the answer: "So if we could prove that something else had the singleton type x.type, we would also prove that it shared all of x’s types". The problems is that `unsafeCoerce[String, Int]("hi")` "should" throw an exception (and actually, so should `unsafeCoerce[String, String]("hi")`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the question is why we can prove. We can't prove for example that String is Int, but can prove that implicitly[B =:= B] is a.type

We can't. Either `implicitly[B =:= B]` is `a.type` or it isn't (i.e. either `implicitly[B =:= B] eq a` is true or it isn't). The code says, basically:

1. *If* it is, then it has both type `B =:= B` and `A =:= A`, so `A` and `B` are the same (because `=:=` is invariant), so `implicitly[A =:= B]` compiles.
2. If it isn't, throw a `MatchError`.

Note that the second case is entirely possible, and it is the one which would happen with a safe definition of `tpEquals`, such as

```
object =:= {
  implicit def tpEquals[A]: A =:= A = new =:=[A,A] {
    def apply(x: A): A = x
  }
}
```

In fact, as my comment says, it would *also* happen with `unsafeCoerce[String, String]("hi")` because two calls to `implicitly` would create two different instances.

Comment: but let's say we have a.type < =:=[A,A] and =:=[B,B]. Compiler allowed us to check if =:=[B,B] is an eq to a.type ([A,A]) ... but! they are definitely not equal because they parametrized by different type parameters (in our case they are abstract). So that's why I said that it is the same as if compiler allowed this check "5 match {case _:String => ... }" .. but it's not even compiled.

Comment: or something like this is not compiled too  class A[A]
  val s = new A[String]
  val i = new A[Int]

  s match {
    case _:i.type =>""
  }

Comment: I suppose that this is allowed to be compiled just because of abstract nature of the parameters. So compiler ignores the parameters and sees a.type as subtype of =:=[Object,Object]. The same for =:=[B,B]

Comment: "=:=[B,B] is an eq to a.type ([A,A])". `=:=[B,B]` is a type, it can't be `eq` to anything. `implicitly[B,B]` is a value of this type, and the compiler can't rule out it being also an `=:=[A, A]` (in case `A` and `B` are the same).

Comment: In the case in your second comment, the compiler knows an `A[String]` can never be an `A[Int]` and therefore it can't be an `a.type`: the types are incompatible.